# Pubnub send only offline messages to email

Tags: pubnub

I saw a few examples on how we can send emails to subscribers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25225300/can-we-receive-pubnub-notifications-by-email). Is there way to perform the action of sending emails only when the subscriber is offline and create a separate email address for the thread.

Comment: That is pretty old and PubNub now offers [BLOCKS which allows you to send email using SendGrid (or any other third party service or your own custom solution)](https://www.pubnub.com/blocks-catalog/sendgrid/) by implementing code that makes xhr call from within the PubNub Network (*serverless computing*).

Comment: but, how do I send it only when the subscriber is offline, also if the subscriber replies to the email I need to able to inject it back into the sender's chat thread.

Comment: You can't always know if someone is online or just disconnected without unsubscribing. So there is a window of time when they may appear to be online but are not. This is the heartbeat window before they *timeout*. The solution you seek is a bit more than just a bit of code. You would be best served to contact [PubNub Support](https://pubnub.com/support) to request a best practice session with one of our solution architects.

Comment: To answer your question about replying to email... I would say don't allow that. Provide a link in the email to get them back to your app to reply to the message. [Flowdock](http://flowdock.com) works like this.